# Api and Ajax loading Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

I've tried to load **Google Maps** with marker from server using **Ajax** and **Api**.

I've tried everything but I don't know where is problem.

**Map is loaded** but **markers** **are not**. I also enclose picture from Postman of my Api response.

*PLEASE HELP ME.* I will be so glad to you.

**Here is the code:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/bicykel/',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (marker, data) {


                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.bicykels.lat, data.bicykels.lng);
                    bounds.extend(latLng);

                    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                    });


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      infoWindow.setContent("<div class='pt-5 bg-dark p-4' style='width:300px';>"+"<h3>"+data.bicykels.name+"</h3>" + " " + data.bicykels.name+"</div>");
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                });



        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Please refresh the page and try again');
        }
    });
```

**Here is the code of Api:**

```
def customer_get_bicykel(request):

uzivatel = request.user.id

bicykels = BicykelSerializer(
    Bicykel.objects.filter(),
    many = True,
    context = {"request": request}
).data

return JsonResponse({"bicykels": bicykels})
```

**And also I enclose screen of api response:**
[Api Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTpD7.png)

*THANK YOU FOR EVRY HELP!*

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out to add the marker to the map. Quoting the google maps JS docs:

```
// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Still have same problem. For me is surprising that it works with Api https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roryheaney/jsonexample/master/locatoins.json but not with my api url.